# Custom implementation of specfic files using productFlavors in Android

Tags: android, android-productflavors, package-name, white-labelling

```
I added a new flavor in my Build.Gradle :: 
    productFlavors {
            pro{
                applicationIdSuffix ".pro" //newpackagename=com.example1.android.pro
               } 
                   }
    My android app structure:
       Project      
       |
        `-- res
             |-- drawable
                      |-- logo.png
       |
        `-- src
            |
             `-- com
                 |-- example1
                        |--- android
                                    |-- db
                                         |-- DatabaseHelper.java
                                         |-- DBObject.java
                                    |-- pro //created new package manually 
                                    |-- AppProperties.java
                                    |-- AndroidTimerFactory.java
```

But I want to start customizing the application for "Pro" and  want to add a new logo.png for that package. How can I do that? where to add the new png image since it lies outside the src folder.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you would have folder under `src` for each product flavor and could then, in your example, store your flavor specific resources under `src/pro/res`

Comment: How to create a new res folder? Which option to select after selecting
src/pro ->new->?

Comment: just create it like you would any other folder (e.g. in AS, right-click on `src` and do New/Directory)....you would then store your png file in `src/pro/res/drawable`.

Comment: I have done these steps and updated the new png. But how to run this version of build? ie the pro version ?

Comment: If you are using Android Studio, there's a "Build Variants" tab on left hand side you can select....you can then select build variant you want to use. If building using gradle then there will be set of standard tasks for each variant e.g. assembleProDebug

Comment: Yes I am using android studio. I selected Build Variants : then pro (Debug or  Release? ) and  then when I run the project, Error : The apk for your current selected variant is not signed. Please speficy the signing configuration for this variant ( when i selected release)
Thank  you SO much for helping me out!

Comment: Sounds like you're not fully setup to build/run release builds (need, as error mentions, info to sign the build).  For the time being I'd suggest selecting debug (which is what you'd typically want until you to to point of publishing app)

Answer (score 0):

Even if it lies outside the src folder it doesn't matter.Gradle will make sure that it is overriden while merging resources. Simply put the png file in src/pro/res/drawable/logo.png